# Using NHibernate to insert into view

Tags: nhibernate, view, insert

If one would want to insert into a view, what would be required to setup on NHibernate to allow this.

Neither

```
<generator class="identity" />
```

nor

```
<generator class="native" />
```

allows insert.

Error I get when I try this is either "Null id" or "Null identifier".

Answer (score 1):

You can not insert, update or delete from a view even with regular SQL commands, nor with NHiberanate. Views are designed for read only purposes.
You should model your class from the original tables in a similar fashion as the view and then you could do any CRUD operation on it.

Comment: You can insert into a view in MsSQL servers, there are some constraints see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335.aspx

Comment: Yes you can insert into a database view and not just SQL Server, Oracle, Firebird... I need updatable view for a specific reason

Answer (score 1):

I have never done this but have you tried assigned:-

```
<generator class="assigned" />
```

> Any modifications, including UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements,
>   must reference columns from only one base table.

See here [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180800.aspx) for more info

And there is one more thing if you use assigned, you have to explicitly specify to NHibernate if the object should be saved or updated by calling either the Save() or Update() method of the ISession.

Comment: Well, I want database to take care of the Id generated. I have a workaround, but I would like to use a cleaner way if possible. Thanks for save/update tip on assigned generator.